# How to overload a method from a foreign package

Tags: common-lisp

Given the szenario that you got a base package which can represent certain stuff via a class  and another package which wants to extend this ability.

```
(defpackage :test
  (:use :cl)
  (:nicknames :test)
  (:export a-test-class
       method-a
       slot-a))

(in-package :test)

(defclass a-test-class ()
  ((slot-a
    :initform 42
    :reader slot-a)))


(defmethod method-a ((a-test-class a-test-class))
  (setf (slot-value a-test-class 'slot-a) 21)
  a-test-class)


(defpackage :exttest
  (:use :cl)
  (:export extended-a-test-class
       method-a))

(in-package :exttest)

(defclass extended-a-test-class (test:a-test-class)
  ((slot-b 
    :reader slot-b
    :initform nil)))

(defmethod method-a ((a-test-class extended-a-test-class))
  (setf (slot-value a-test-class 'slot-a) 23)
  a-test-class)
```

Now I got a function which does not really do anthying but go over a list of instances of  `a-test-class` and `extended-a-test-class` and is supposed to call `method-a` on all of them, expecting them to change, respectively to their type. E.g. `(slot-a (method-a a-test-class-instance)) > 21` and `(slot-a (method-a extended-a-test-class-instance)) > 23`

But trying to do this, I run into the problem of correctly calling method-a as:

```
(defparameter *test-instance* (make-instance 'test:a-test-class))
(defparameter *ext-test-instance* (make-instance 'exttest:extended-a-test-class))

(test:slot-a (test:method-a *test-instance*))
> 21
(test:slot-a (test:method-a *ext-test-instance*))
> 21
```

or

```
(test:slot-a (exttest:method-a *test-instance*))
(test:slot-a (exttest:method-a *ext-test-instance*))

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002B03193}>:
  There is no applicable method for the generic function
    #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION EXTTEST:METHOD-A (1)>
  when called with arguments
    (#<TEST:A-TEST-CLASS {10041148A3}>)
```

Is neither really working for me, as in either way I am not able to compile, or the effect of the method is not as desired. If the classes and method definitions are in the same package, everything works fine though.

Therefore: **How can I call a method on an instance without needing to address the corresponding package?** *(If I am not able to do so, I'd like to know how my expectations for OO-Programming in Common-Lisp are misguided)*

For an "working" example, of what output I'd like, I coded this c++ program. I do known that CLOS works different from the "common" Object Oriented System, due to the fact that methods do not "belong" to classes. But I'd expect any object oriented system to (somehow) be able to behave/be used like this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
  class sub {
  public:
    virtual sub* method_a() = 0;
  };

  class a_test_class : public sub
  {
  protected:
    int value;  
  public:
   a_test_class(int val) : value(val) {
   }

   a_test_class* method_a() {
     value = 21;
     return this;
   }

   int get_value() {
      return value;
   }
  };
}

namespace exttest {

  class extended_a_test_class : public test::a_test_class {

  public:
    extended_a_test_class(int val) : a_test_class(val) {  }

   extended_a_test_class* method_a() {
     std::cout << "calling overloaded method" << std::endl;
     this->value = 23;
     return this;
   }
  };
}


int main(int argc,const char* argv[]) {
  test::a_test_class* atc = new test::a_test_class(42);
  test::a_test_class* eatc = new exttest::extended_a_test_class(42);
  std::cout << atc->method_a()->get_value() << std::endl;
  std::cout << eatc->method_a()->get_value() << std::endl;
  delete atc;
  delete eatc;
}

> ./a.out
21
calling overloaded method
23
```

Comment: Methods may not belong to classes, but they do belong to generic functions.  I find it generally helpful to define the generic functions (using `defgeneric`) before defining methods for them.  At least SBCL also gives warnings when you implicitly create generic functions with `defmethod`.  That might have helped you here.

Comment: @Svante I did see that there were new generic methods being defined, but I did not know how to prevent that. But still a valuable advise, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `(:import-from test #:method-a)` to `(defpackage :exttest)` so that the two symbols `test:method-a` and `exttest:method-a` will be *identical*.

As it is defined now, there are *two* separate generic functions `exttest:method-a` and `test:method-a`, each with a single method; the former is not defined for `exttest:extended-a-test-class` while the latter does not have a separate method for `exttest:extended-a-test-class`.

Answer (score 2):

Just as you may need to write a package prefix to make sure that you're referring to the right symbol when you *call* a function or method, so too you might need to use a package prefix when you're defining additional methods on a generic function.  For instance, consider a package named "FOO", and a generic function named "FROB" in package "FOO":

```
(defpackage #:foo 
  (:export #:frob)
  (:use "COMMON-LISP"))

(in-package #:foo)

(defgeneric frob (object))

(defmethod frob ((x string))
  (format t "frobbing string ~a" x))

;; call frob 
(frob "some string")
```

While in another package named "ΒΑR", to refer to the symbol named "FROB" in the package named "FOO", we have to write `foo:frob`.  This goes for calling the generic functoin, as well as defining new methods on it.

```
(defpackage #:bar
  (:use "COMMON-LISP"))

(defmethod foo:frob ((x integer))
  (format t "frobbing integer ~A" x))

;; call frob 
(foo:frob "some string")
(foo:frob 45)
```